# How to import module ember-localstorage-adapter with Ember-CLI?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I tried to import ember-localstorage-adapter as

```
import DS.LSAdapter from "ember-localstorage-adapter";
```

But I got the error

> Error: Line 5: Missing from after import

Do I need to compile ember-localstorage-adapter with ES6 Module Transpiler?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**UPDATE**

ember-localstorage-adapter is now an ember-cli addon, so to add it to asset pipeline just run:

`ember install ember-localstorage-adapter` for latest ember-cli versions (after 1.5)

or

`npm install --save-dev ember-localstorage-adapter` for versions before 1.5

And go to step 4, to configure the adapter and serializer.

If you're using an old version of ember-cli, please use the steps below:

I did the following steps to import the ember-localstorage-adapter:

1- Created a new ember application with:

```
ember new <someapp>
```

2- Installed the ember-localstorage-adapter dependency with bower:

```
bower install ember-localstorage-adapter --save
```

3- Added the `app.import("bower_components/ember-localstorage-adapter/localstorage_adapter.js");` before the `module.exports = app.toTree();` call inside of `Brocfile.js`

This is the entire Brocfile.js:

```
/* global require, module */

 var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

 var app = new EmberApp(); 

 app.import("bower_components/ember-localstorage-adapter/localstorage_adapter.js");

 module.exports = app.toTree();
```

4- Used the `DS.LSAdapter` as the default adapter creating a file called `app/adapters/application.js` with the following content:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.LSAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'yournamespace'
});
```

5- Used the `DS.LSSerializer` as the default serializer creating a file called `app/serializers/application.js` with the following content:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.LSSerializer.extend();
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a heads up, I had to add:

import DS from "ember-data";

to app/adapters/application.js and app/serializers/application.js

Comment: Thank you @Sam! I updated the answer with your comment

Comment: Also remember to restart the ember server, Livereload obviously doesn't reload Brocfile changes, that one got me

Comment: Could you update your answer since now it's using ember-cli addon ? :)

Comment: has something changed since then? I followed the instructions above (using npm and then step 4 & 5) but I get following error:
    Error while processing route: products.index Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

Comment: @mohamnag This still works fine. I think your problem is related to some specific addon or your own code.

Comment: my bad, I had to restart the broccoli (ember cli)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was solved by @Marcio's solution. **BUT** I also needed to update my node version.

The issue persisted on node-v0.10.0, I [updated node](http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs%20updated%20node) to node-v0.12.0 and then @Marcio's solution worked.

To be clear, you should still do everything in @Marcio's post, but if it still does not solve the issue, try updating node.